# Create one master page compatible with Desktop and mobile - Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, mobile, themes, master-pages, sharepoint-2013

I need design a master page for SharePoint 2013. 
This master page is compatible with Desktop and mobile view
How to start? 
I have experience with desktop master page but not with mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is not possible to have the same master page to be fit in the desktop as well as mobile application view, for that you have to create two different master pages. using the media query or the jquery, which can identify the view of the site and adjusts itself accordingly.

Hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, i'm learning Responsive Web Design to do this work :)

Comment: It is possible using bootstrap.css ! Also, Microsoft announced the creation of a responsibe masterpage for SharePoint 2013 & 2016. I think it is already released by now. Check these links:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vesku/2016/03/03/announcing-responsive-ui-package-for-sharepoint-on-premises-2013-and-2016/
http://www.collabshow.com/2016/03/03/microsoft-announces-responsive-ui-package-for-sharepoint-2013-and-2016-available-now/